# Cron Daemon error With PHP Cron job

Tags: php, cron

So I'm fairly new with Cron Jobs and I've run into a wall with trying to get this specific cron job to work. All I want is for a PHP webpage to be accessed daily. By accessing the PHP page, the cron job will activate the script inside which sends out an email to specific users. Here is the cron job code:

```
php -q /home/sitename/public_html/scripts/emailnotifications.php
```

Unfortunately, everyday at 1AM, I receive this error message and no one receives their email.

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext/php_bz2.dll' - 

C:\xampp\php\ext/php_bz2.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext/php_bz2.dll' - C:\xampp\php\ext/php_bz2.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br />
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext/php_mbstring.dll' - C:\xampp\php\ext/php_mbstring.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext/php_mbstring.dll' - C:\xampp\php\ext/php_mbstring.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br />
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext/php_exif.dll' - C:\xampp\php\ext/php_exif.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext/php_exif.dll' - C:\xampp\php\ext/php_exif.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br />
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext/php_gd2.dll' - C:\xampp\php\ext/php_gd2.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext/php_gd2.dll' - C:\xampp\php\ext/php_gd2.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br />
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext/php_gettext.dll' - C:\xampp\php\ext/php_gettext.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext/php_gettext.dll' - C:\xampp\php\ext/php_gettext.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br />
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext/php_imap.dll' - C:\xampp\php\ext/php_imap.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext/php_imap.dll' - C:\xampp\php\ext/php_imap.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br />
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext/php_mysql.dll' - C:\xampp\php\ext/php_mysql.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext/php_mysql.dll' - C:\xampp\php\ext/php_mysql.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br />
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext/php_mysqli.dll' - C:\xampp\php\ext/php_mysqli.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext/php_mysqli.dll' - C:\xampp\php\ext/php_mysqli.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br />
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext/php_pdo_mysql.dll' - C:\xampp\php\ext/php_pdo_mysql.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext/php_pdo_mysql.dll' - C:\xampp\php\ext/php_pdo_mysql.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br />
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext/php_pdo_odbc.dll' - C:\xampp\php\ext/php_pdo_odbc.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext/php_pdo_odbc.dll' - C:\xampp\php\ext/php_pdo_odbc.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br />
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext/php_pdo_sqlite.dll' - C:\xampp\php\ext/php_pdo_sqlite.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext/php_pdo_sqlite.dll' - C:\xampp\php\ext/php_pdo_sqlite.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br />
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext/php_soap.dll' - C:\xampp\php\ext/php_soap.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext/php_soap.dll' - C:\xampp\php\ext/php_soap.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br />
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext/php_sockets.dll' - C:\xampp\php\ext/php_sockets.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext/php_sockets.dll' - C:\xampp\php\ext/php_sockets.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br />
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext/php_sqlite.dll' - C:\xampp\php\ext/php_sqlite.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext/php_sqlite.dll' - C:\xampp\php\ext/php_sqlite.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br />
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext/php_sqlite3.dll' - C:\xampp\php\ext/php_sqlite3.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext/php_sqlite3.dll' - C:\xampp\php\ext/php_sqlite3.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br />
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext/php_xmlrpc.dll' - C:\xampp\php\ext/php_xmlrpc.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext/php_xmlrpc.dll' - C:\xampp\php\ext/php_xmlrpc.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br />
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext/php_ming.dll' - C:\xampp\php\ext/php_ming.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext/php_ming.dll' - C:\xampp\php\ext/php_ming.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br />
PHP Warning:  Cannot open 'C:\xampp\php\extras\browscap.ini' for reading in Unknown on line 0
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Cannot open 'C:\xampp\php\extras\browscap.ini' for reading in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br />
No input file specified.
```

I don't have shell access to the server or access to any server settings files (except php.ini). What should I do to get this script to run daily?

Comment: Cron job on a windows machine O.o?

Comment: This looks like a problem with the PHP installation, you'll need to contact the server administrator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like that you copied your full php.ini from your windows machine (probably the dev environment) up to a remote server which is running some linux distribution.

The extensions listed in your xampp provided php.ini won't work this way over there. If you are certain that you want to copy the whole php.ini from your dev machine, (you most likely won't need that) you will probably have to remove or edit the `extension=` lines to fit the environment (They most likely should end with `.so` at least and have a different path). Checking every path related setting would be wise too.

(Using full paths in every `extension=` line is foolish since there's [`extension_dir`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.extension-dir))