# Yii2 - PHP Core Warning - yii\base\ErrorException

Tags: php, yii2

Whenever I open my this project in localhost after coming office. This error i got everyday. But, after refreshing 4-5 times, this error is getting removed and pages will start working fine.

> PHP Core Warning - yii\base\ErrorException
>
> PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   '/opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/php_pdo_sqlite.dll'
>   - /opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/php_pdo_sqlite.dll:
>   cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

[image]

I'm not getting or i'm not able to know which file is disturbed or having error. So, if anyone having idea or suggestion feel free to share. Sorry, i'm not uploading any php file, because i don't know which code I've to share with you all people.

Comment: `.dll` in linux ? configure your php configuration correctly. PHP Extensions are in `.so` format.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cron Daemon error With PHP Cron job](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13967207/cron-daemon-error-with-php-cron-job)

Comment: Hi @Jigar : Which file to make as `.so` format .?

Comment: @Jigar means that your php.ini file is trying to load .dll files. This is obviously incorect, as you seem to be running linux, and .dll files are only for windows (well spotted btw!). Check with your system admin if you have one, have them take a look at your php.ini file

Comment: Ok @JoeMiller : Thanks. I will contact system administrator.

Comment: you can hide it fir you like but this
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);