# php: warning unable to load dynamic libraty php_openssl.dll not found

Tags: php, xampp

I get this warning :

> Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/php_openssl.dll' - /opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/php_openssl.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

Comment: might be folder permission issue! apply folder permission to `777` or `644`

Comment: i've tried , but didn't fix it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13967207/cron-daemon-error-with-php-cron-job

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be trying to load a **Windows** dll on a **Linux** machine. Windows calls these things `.dll`, where as Linux uses `.so`.

This error shows up because you have in one of your `php.ini` files, the statement `extension=php_openssl.dll`. You need to find that ini file, and remove that line. You can find the ini files that PHP uses, by:

- `php --ini` on the command line
- check output of phpinfo()s first section "Loaded Configuration File" and "Additional .ini files parsed"

After you have found the ini file(s), look in each of them for "php_openssl.dll", and remove that line. Then restart your Web server.